# Where are these mysterious OU documents?

Tags: books-generally, hechsher-certification

I was recently reading a [Halachically Speaking article](http://www.thehalacha.com/attach/Volume4/Issue2.pdf) and noticed that in many places in the footnotes, a reference to an OU Document is made. For example:

> Refer to OU Document A-94

Is this some sort of internal document, or is there a well-known place one can access these documents?

Answer (score 6):

I'm *guessing* that it's a semi-internal system that you can probably find out more about by contacting the OU. If it's referenced in a book, the OU must have some sort of research library. I couldn't find anything on the OU's website, but a [quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=OU%20Document%20A-94&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&source=hp&q=%22OU%20Document%20A-94%22&pbx=1&oq=%22OU%20Document%20A-94%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4859l5429l0l5647l2l2l0l0l0l0l181l355l0.2l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=de4ce0a5d4a08049&biw=1227&bih=672) of "OU Document A-94" led to [this PDF](https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108110437W-25%20Breakfast%20Cereals.pdf), which refers to the document which you mention in footnote 31. The footnote reads:

> Horav Yisroel Belsky Shlita. Refer to OU Document A-94, see Pischei Halacha (Kashrus) page 118:3 quoting the opinion of the author of the Be’er Moshe (Stern), Bishul Yisroel pages 177-178, Teshuvos from Horav Falk in sefer ibid: pages 29-31.

I don't know for sure the document is available, but that footnote ought to give you some other places to continue your research.

**EDIT:**

I've emailed the OU and they sent me the document. I've left it in [my public Dropbox folder, here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8372230/A94.doc). This doesn't answer the question of how their catalog is set up, but this should help you.

Comment: That PDF appears to be a carbon copy of my original PDF...

Comment: Oh, well, I'm emailing the OU at the moment, so, we shall see if they can shed light. Also, a mutual friend of ours (who binds books) might be able to pull weight at the OU and find out more, if I can't.

Comment: Did they by any chance tell you where they're kept? Irony: this new document references yet another document in their footnotes...

Comment: No they did not. I emailed a certain Rabbi Grossman. His contact information is on the OU website.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is an internal system innovated years ago by [*Moreinu HaRav* Dovid Mintz, *shlit"a*](https://www.kby.org/english/staff/?id=82), as an attempt to organize the responsa, etc. of the *poskim* of the OU on halachic issues to indicate what are the official halachic positions of the O-U. (Note that it can only work where the O-U's policies are actually consistent and based on halachic rulings of their *poskim*, as opposed to policies based on other concerns such as *chodosh*.)

Comment: Why can't it work for policies based on fiscal concerns? Is it not just a catalog of positions?

Comment: *Halachic* positions/rulings, not extralegal motivations.

Comment: So it could work for any position, just they choose to limit it to Halachic motivations? Or are you just making up what they do and do not include in those documents?

Comment: I've never worked at the OU nor do I have regular access to the documents. My understanding, however, is that they were created as a way to try and keep a relatively consistent *psak halacha*. I believe people used to ask the OU about their halachik policy with regard to specific rulings and the OU unfortunately didn't have clear answers and/or a consistent approach. The documentation system innovated by Rabbi Mintz was meant to address this issue. This was to my knowledge a halachic system, not a general policy system.

Comment: I.e. each document effectively serves as a formal ruling. This isn't to say that it says "we pasken x on issue y". Rather, it might contain the final teshuvot of the OU's 3 poskim on an issue. (I've seen for example one document where Rav Schechter sent a shayla regarding contemporary dairy to Rav Nachum Rabinovitch. No answer was included in the document presumably because Rav Schechter was not convinced by his response and "paskened" the original safek. Likely this was outvoted by Rav Belsky, z"l, and y"l, Rabbi Genack.

Comment: Nonetheless, I don't think all OU policies are rooted in these documents/"rulings". E.g. my understanding of the OU's position on Yoshon is that it is more of a non-position, because the OU is not willing to dramatically change the already accepted practice. A more cynical view (such as my own) is that the OU's financial investment in certifying chodosh has some influence in the OU's policy. Rav Belsky z"l was himself "makpid on yoshon" and my sense is that he viewed the OU's role as not one of ruling on the issue but as ruling on other issues.

Comment: @DoubleAA I.e. I assume he felt there were other valid viewpoints and he was not ruling on the issue by allowing the OU to certify chodosh as"kosher". I assume that this is perhaps also the current position of Rabbi Genack, shlit"a. Rav Schechter indeed is meikil himself I believe assuming, based on the Aruch HaShulchan, that there is a widespread valid and established minhag Ashkenaz to follow the Ohr Chodosh even shelo bshaat hadechak. I'm not sure if that means he would not allow Sefardim to rely on the OU (or e.g. if in a majority Ashkenaz country they too can keep alleged Ashkenazi kulot)

Comment: @DoubleAA In short, my understanding is that the documents are halachic teshuvot (or sh'eilot) that influence the OU's positions but do not determine them. (Or perhaps the documents do determine the OUs positions, where the dcouments are indeed formally generated. However, where a psak might create significant complications deemed unjustified, they won't compose them in the first place.)

Comment: @DoubleAA (I should also add that they also include the back and forth. E.g. with regard to the OU's fluctuating position on Yak's milk derived casein in tuna with regard to Tibetan peasant's bishul akum and China's corrupt govenment practices, Rav Schechter's initial lenient position is included even though it was passionately overruled by Rav Belsky (which is to say Rav Schechter's retraction is also included in the OU doc; And indeed tuna is once again pareve, which goes to show the OU's industrial clout.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps I should edit some of the above into the answer... The OU docs are a fascinating and informative read on many levels. Too bad they are not (to my knowledge) publicly accessible .

Comment: This answer could be improved significantly with the addition of elaboration on "I believe" to indicate where this belief comes from and with the subtraction of the distracting parenthetical editorializing. That is, I don't see a reason why an answer explaining what these documents are is enhanced with a description or critique of how the OU determines operational policy.